# mercurial - list users with changeset in default not in stable

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to be able to output a list of users that have commits in default (or, more specifically, the bookmark @) that are not yet in stable. To do this with git I would do:

```
git log stable..at --format="%an" | sort | uniq
```

The closest I've got is:

```
hg log -r "@ - stable" | grep user:
```

Answer (score 3):

The following command should do the trick:

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(@) - ancestors(stable)' -T '{author|person}\n' | sort -u
```

The `-T` or `--template` option allows you to configure the output; see `hg help templates` for details.

The `ancestors(stable)` revset should work for both a `stable` bookmark and a named branch called `stable`; `ancestors(default)` can be substituted for `ancestors(@)` to capture the entire default branch and not just the part following the bookmark `@`. To further customize author information (e.g. to extract email information only), see `hg help templates` again; `{author}` will provide the full author information, `{author|email}` will provide their email address, `{author|emailuser}` will provide the local part of the email address, etc. Above, `{author|person}` will provide the real name to reflect the semantics of `%an` in Git.